# Algorithm for total idle time for a process based on average

Tags: java, algorithm

This was asked during an online interview process many days back, the question follows like this:

A computer system uses a preemptive process scheduling methodology called *Less than average first* which works as follows:

- A process that has the remaining execution time lesser than the average execution times of all processes is executed.
- If multiple processes satisfying the first condition are found, the process which arrived earlier is executed. If no processes exist that do not satisfy this, then the smallest remaining process is chosen first.

Given the arrival times and the total execution times of each process, find the total time for which each process remaining idle before its execution is completed.

**Example:** Each line contains arrival time and the remaining execution time:

```
1 4
2 2
3 1
```

**Output:**
Total time for which each process remains idle before its execution is completed.

```
4
```

**Explanation:**

```
At time = 1, only one process exists so it will be executed.

At time = 2, the avg. execution time is (3+2)/2 = 2.5, the remaining execution time of the 2nd process is lesser than the average. Hence end process will be executed.
```

Hence the final processes execution sequence for each time unit is:

```
1 2 2 3 1 1 1
```

Method signature is:

```
int process(int input[][]) {

}
```

I tried to understand this question by reading it many times, but I am not able to understand, can you please help me with how to solve this?

Comment: You're scheduling processes to run on a CPU, at most one can run at any one time. Time advances by one unit at a time. Every tick you decide which process to let run based on the rules. For every process that has arrived, wants to run, but is not running, increase the return value by one.

Comment: "I'm not able to understand" is not a question we can really work with. Are there parts of it you do understand? (if none of this makes any sense to you whatsoever, the job would probably make you miserable anyway, be glad you didn't get it...)

Comment: @dratenik, can you please explain this `At time = 2, the avg. execution time is (3+2)/2 = 2.5`. Also how the output `4` for this sample example?

Comment: At time 2, process 1 is there from before (3 time left) and 2 has arrived (2 time left) - (3+2)/2

Comment: For the origin of 4 see "increase the return value by one" above. Process 1 contributes 3 by being kept asleep during time 2,3,4, process 3 contributes 1 by being asleep at time 3.

Comment: @dratenik, so is it denominator value is always 2? Also at time 3 how the average is calculated for the given example. Also why the execution process is always `1 2 2 3 1 1 1` for this example. I mean why not, `1 2 3 2 1 1 1` or 1 2 3 1 1 1 2` etc

Comment: You are computing the average of processes that have already arrived and have non-zero time left. The denominator is the number of those at the current time.

Comment: ... because that's the order you get when you follow the rules? At time 3 you have (p1:3) (p2:1) (p3:1), you have to select p2 or p3 because they satisfy condition one (the average is 5/3), and it is going to be p2 because condition two.

Comment: Technically the official solution is wrong. Rule one should be "less or equal", otherwise there is nothing to schedule at time 1. And the rules will get stuck if multiple processes arrive at the same time with the same time requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a method `getNextProcess` to determine the next process to run and then build a scheduler that actually processes the input and adds up the waiting times. This way you can simulate the whole processing and then have the result in the end.

Determining the next process to run (implementing the rules as stated in the question):

```java
static Optional<Process> getNextProcess(List<Process> processes) {
    if (processes.isEmpty()) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    // calculate average
    double avg = processes.stream()
            .mapToInt(p -> p.getRemainingTime())
            .average().getAsDouble();

    // return first process with 'remaining time < avg'
    // simultaneously process with smallest remaining time
    Process nextProcess = null;
    int minRemainingTime = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (Process p : processes) {
        if (p.getRemainingTime() < avg) {
            return Optional.of(p);
        }
        if (p.getRemainingTime() < minRemainingTime) {
            nextProcess = p;
            minRemainingTime = p.getRemainingTime();
        }
    }
    return Optional.ofNullable(nextProcess);
}
```

This is how the simulator/scheduler can look like:

```java
static int process(int[][] input) {
    // transform the 2d-array into a custom object for convenience
    List<Process> incomingProcesses = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        incomingProcesses.add(new Process(i + 1, input[i][0], input[i][1]));
    }

    // simulate scheduling
    int time = 1;
    int totalWaitingTime = 0;
    List<Process> currentProcesses = new ArrayList<>();
    while (!incomingProcesses.isEmpty() || !currentProcesses.isEmpty()) {
        // handle new processes that arrive at this time step
        final int finalTime = time;
        List<Process> newProcesses = incomingProcesses.stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getArrivalTime() == finalTime)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        currentProcesses.addAll(newProcesses);
        incomingProcesses.removeAll(newProcesses);

        // remove processes with no remaining time
        currentProcesses.removeIf(p -> p.getRemainingTime() <= 0);

        // increase total waiting time (reduction follows later)
        totalWaitingTime += currentProcesses.size();

        // get next process and if found,
        //   reduce its remaining time and decrease total waiting time
        Optional<Process> nextProcess = getNextProcess(currentProcesses);
        if (nextProcess.isPresent()) {
            Process p = nextProcess.get();
            System.out.println("Process " + p.getId());
            p.setRemainingTime(p.getRemainingTime() - 1);
            totalWaitingTime -= 1; // reduction since this process actually run
        }

        time++; // move to next time step
    }
    return totalWaitingTime;
}
```

Let's test that:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int result = process(new int[][]{
            {1, 4},
            {2, 2},
            {3, 1}
    });
    System.out.println("The result is: " + result);
}
```

Output:

```
Process 1
Process 2
Process 2
Process 3
Process 1
Process 1
Process 1
The result is: 4
```

Comment: @dratenik I extended my answer now to show the correct output (total waiting time) and the executed processes.

Comment: I have 2 more test cases mentioned in the exam. ` { 5, 1 }, { 6, 1 }, { 7, 6 }, { 6, 2 }, { 6, 3 }, { 7, 1 } ` output `12`. Another ` { 1, 3 }, { 1, 2 }, { 3, 1 }, { 4, 2 }, { 3, 2 }, { 4, 5 }, { 1, 1 } ` output `23`. I tried this solution, but getting different results.